# Error undefined - al pasar valor de una query a variable en Node.js con passport

Tags: nodejs, variables, passport

Soy novato en node.js y estoy intentando crear un apartado de login. De momento iba todo correcto pero al intentar almacenar el valor de una QUERY de Node en una constante con nombre ROWS el valor no se almacena en ella y me devuelve UNDEFINED si lo imprimo por consola. Alguien sabe el por que? Si me puede echar alguien una mano os lo agradecería. El código es el siguiente:

```
passport.use('local-login', new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, username, password, done) => {
  const rows = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE eMail = ?", [username]);
  console.log(rows[0]);
    if(rows.length > 0){
    const user = rows[0];
    const validPassword = await helpers.matchPassword(password, user.password);
    if(validPassword){
      done(null, user, null);
    }else{
      done(null, false, null);
    }
  }else{
      return done(null, false, null);
  }
}));
```

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

no se de donde sale el objeto "connection", pero si está utilizando por ejemplo MySQL debe ejecutar el método asíncrono si está empleando una librería que lo soporte.

En caso contrario puede usar promesas o then().

Prueba el sigueinte código :)

```
passport.use('local-login', new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, username, password, done) => {
    // Esto lo converimos como promesa
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE eMail = ?", [username], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            // Error
            return reject(err);
        }
        // Todo ok
        resolve(result);
    });
  }).then(rows => {

console.log(rows[0]);
    if(rows.length > 0){
    const user = rows[0];
    const validPassword = await helpers.matchPassword(password, user.password);
    if(validPassword){
      done(null, user, null);
    }else{
      done(null, false, null);
    }
  }else{
      return done(null, false, null);
  }
}));


  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // Error
  });
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, con el objeto 'connection' no hay problema, el problema es que no almacena el valor de la Query en la constante rows. No sé por qué, tiene que ver algo con promesas o then? Si me puedes poner algún ejemplo de código te lo agradecería, llevo 2 días con Node y se me escapan muchos aspectos que aún no controlo.

Comment: Te modifiqué la respuesta :) a ver si te funciona así. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

He probado como me has dicho y no me ha funcionado pero ya tengo la solución.

```
passport.use('local-login', new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async(req, username, password, done) => {
  const rows = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE eMail = ?", [username], async(error, rows) => {
    console.log(rows[0]);
      if(rows.length > 0){
      const user = rows[0];
      const validPassword = await helpers.matchPassword(password, user.password);
      if(validPassword){
        done(null, user, null);
      }else{
        done(null, false, null);
      }
    }else{
        return done(null, false, null);
    }
  });

}));
```

Este es el código que me ha funcionado al final, espero que a alguien le resulte de ayuda. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas Gonzalo !!!!
¡ Saludos ! :)